# How to assign and group obj by?

Tags: javascript

I am running the following:

```
const result = data.map(function(item) {
  const ditem = dictionary.find(d => d.state == item.state);
  if(ditem) {
    item.date = (item.date.toString().slice(4)+item.date.toString().slice(0,2)).match(/.{1,2}/g).join("/")
    return {
      ...item,
      "lat": ditem.lat ,
      "long": ditem.long
      }
    }
  return item;
});
```

Which gives:

```
  {
    "date": "04/21/20",
    "state": "AK",
    "positive": 329,
    "negative": 10790,
    "pending": null,
    "hospitalizedCurrently": 42,
    "hospitalizedCumulative": 36,
    "inIcuCurrently": null,
    "inIcuCumulative": null,
    "onVentilatorCurrently": null,
    "onVentilatorCumulative": null,
    "recovered": 168,
    "hash": "10d6907c6ec12caa4a5896fc50c4a3f06c836c0c",
    "dateChecked": "2020-04-21T20:00:00Z",
    "death": 9,
    "hospitalized": 36,
    "total": 11119,
    "totalTestResults": 11119,
    "posNeg": 11119,
    "fips": "02",
    "deathIncrease": 0,
    "hospitalizedIncrease": 0,
    "negativeIncrease": 987,
    "positiveIncrease": 8,
    "totalTestResultsIncrease": 995,
    "lat": "9875.33.00",
    "long": "-8371.42.00"
  },
```

But I need all values under a group data, exactly like this as this is the format I use for other parts of the code:

```
State: "AK"
Lat: 34.802075
Long: 38.996815000000005
data: Array(92)
  0: {date: "1/22/20", positive: 0, death: 0, recovered: 0}
  1: {date: "1/23/20", positive: 0, death: 0, recovered: 0}
  2: {date: "1/24/20", positive: 0, death: 0, recovered: 0}
```

The coordinates are in a separate file which I grab and insert based on `State` name

```
item.date = item.date.toString();
item.date = (item.date.toString().slice(4)+item.date.toString().slice(0,2)).match(/.{1,2}/g).join("/")
```

I think I am almost there but I am not sure where to add the bit to get the lat and long too, so this

```
const ditem = dictionary.find(d => d.state == item.state);
```

needs to be added to

```
const formatted = Object.assign(
    {},data.map(
        area => {
            return {
                "state": area["state"],
                "lat": area["lat"],
                "long": area["long"],
                "data": Object.assign({},Object.keys(area)
                    .map(
                        date => ({ 
                            date: area[date], negative: area[date], positive: area[date], pending: area[date], hospitalizedCurrently: area[date], 
                            hospitalizedCumulative: area[date], inIcuCurrently: area[date], inIcuCumulative: area[date], onVentilatorCurrently: area[date],
                            onVentilatorCumulative: area[date], recovered: area[date], dateChecked: area[date], death: area[date],
                            hospitalized: area[date], total: area[date], totalTestResults: area[date], posNeg: area[date],
                            fips: area[date], deathIncrease: area[date], hospitalizedIncrease: area[date], negativeIncrease: area[date],
                            positiveIncrease: area[date], totalTestResultsIncrease: area[date]
                        })
                    )
                )
            };
        }
    )
);
```

Another important thing is the date format, I use:

```
item.date = (item.date.toString().slice(4)+item.date.toString().slice(0,2)).match(/.{1,2}/g).join("/")
```

Because the date we receive is like: `date: 20200421` while we need it like `24/4/20` so need to convert that too while building the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping you may reduce by state.

```js
const data = [
  {state: 'fr', date:'20200421', city: 'lyon', positive:1},
  {state: 'fr', date:'20200422', city:'paris', positive:2},
  {state: 'en', date:'20200423', city:'london', positive:3},
  {state: 'en', date:'20200424', city:'oxford', positive:4}
]
const dictionary = [{state: 'en', lat: 52.6412763, long: -1.2767434,}, {state:'fr', lat:45.7731412, long:4.8628491}]
const stateToCities = data.reduce((acc, { state, ...item }) => {
  // for big array use hashmap for dictionary instead
  const ditem = dictionary.find(d => d.state == state)
  if (!ditem) return acc // no nest level, early exit

  const group = acc.get(ditem) || []
  const withoutState = { }
  group.push({
    ...item,
    // maybe you did not to modify existing item, up to you
    date: (item.date.toString().slice(4)+item.date.toString().slice(0,2)).match(/.{1,2}/g).join("/")
  })
  return acc.set(ditem, group)
}, new Map())

const payloadAsInQuestion = [...stateToCities.entries()].map(([{state, long, lat}, cities]) => {
  return {
    state, long, lat,
    data: cities
  }
})
// if you need array
console.log('stringified' , JSON.stringify(payloadAsInQuestion, null, 2))
```

Note by the way that it is a bit paradoxal: you want to "update" item in one go but look up in dictionary which is an array. So you may use a hashmap for the dictionary instead

Comment: looking at exactly this tho `State: "AK"
Lat: 34.802075
Long: 38.996815000000005
data: Array(92)
  0: {date: "1/22/20", positive: 0, death: 0, recovered: 0}
  1: {date: "1/23/20", positive: 0, death: 0, recovered: 0}
  2: {date: "1/24/20", positive: 0, death: 0, recovered: 0}...`

Comment: @rob.m while I take into account your data, please update your post with your data so people don't have to make their own dataset

Comment: I have, what you see on the question is my data

Comment: I have also posted what the expected result I'm looking for is, your bit doesn't look like what I am expecting

Comment: and here is the fiddle if you want to play with real data https://jsfiddle.net/47wvts0e/

Comment: @rob.m You misued Map in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tarnm8wx/
you just need to convert stateToCities to json first

Comment: @rob.m also I think your main preoccupation is the grouping and you are able to handle the rest, if not I may further update if you ask

Comment: ok but on your bit we have "state": "AK", and lat": "9875.33.00" on the cities obj. We need also cities to be called data, or it will be confusing for future users if we don't output the format we're asking in the question. But you're almost there tho

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212403/discussion-between-rob-m-and-grodzi).

Comment: I have updated payload it should be pretty closed to expected output, I think you just need to filter out the fields you want or not when you push the city to the group

Comment: can we remove lat, long and state from data?